# C# .net ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, ado.net

On Registration page I have the error

> "C# .net ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized"

But If I give comments to "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery" on Registration page the this error goes to login page. I am unable to register and login on this.

***Login Page:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Security;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LENOVO;Initial Catalog=Onl9Shopping;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123"); 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Onl9Shopping;Trusted_Connection=Yes;;Pooling=False");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ImageButton4_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText="checksecurity ";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Txtusername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Txtpassword.Text);

        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@ret", SqlDbType.Int);
        p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

        SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        p3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int r = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.Parameters["@ret"].Value);
        string status = cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value.ToString();
        string loggedname = cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value.ToString();

        if (r == -1)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Wrong Username";
        }
        else if (r == -2)
        {
            Label1.Text = "wrong Password";
        }
        else
        {
            Session["name"] = loggedname;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tk = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Txtusername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), false, status);
            string s = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tk);
            HttpCookie ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,s);
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
            Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
        }
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
    }
```

***Registration Page:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Registartion : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Onl9Shopping;Trusted_Connection=Yes");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void getregno()
    {
        string query = "select max (registrationno) from register";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        Txtreg.Text = (Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]) + Convert.ToInt16(1)).ToString();
    }
    protected void btncheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "select username from register";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int a = 0;
        a = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        while (a > b)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[b][0].ToString().Equals(TxtUserName.Text))
            {
                c = 1;

            }
            b++;
        }
        if (c == 1)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Name already exist !!..";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Name available";
        }
        Label1.Visible=true;
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "select username from register";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int a = 0;
        a = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        while (a > b)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[b][0].ToString().Equals(TxtUserName.Text))
            {
                c = 1;
            }
            b++;
        }
        if (c == 1)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Name already exist !!..";
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();            
            string query1 = "Insert into register(Name,FatherName,Gender,Address,Country,State,City,Pin,Phn,Email,Username,Password,SecurityQuestion,Hint)values(@Name,@Fathername,@Gender,@Address,@Country,@State,@City,@Pin,@Phn,@Email,@Username,@Password,@SecurityQuestion,@Hint)";
            cmd.CommandText = query1;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Txtname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", Txtfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", DropDownList1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Txtaddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Txtcountry.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", Txtstate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", Txtcity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin", Txtpin.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phn", Txtphn.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Txtemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TxtUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Txtpassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityQuestion", DropDownList2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hint", Txthint.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();

            Txtname.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtfname.Text = string.Empty;

            Txtaddress.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtcountry.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtstate.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtcity.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtpin.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtphn.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtemail.Text = string.Empty;
            TxtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
            Txtpassword.Text = string.Empty;

            Txtaddress.Text = string.Empty;
            Txthint.Text = string.Empty;
            Label2.Text = "Data sumitted ";
            Label2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the correct code of these pages?

Answer (score 0):

There no commandtype for the click event for ImageButton1:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();            
            string query1 = "Insert intoregister(Name,FatherName,Gender,Address,Country,State,City,Pin,Phn,Email,Username,Password,SecurityQuestion,Hint)values(@Name,@Fathername,@Gender,@Address,@Country,@State,@City,@Pin,@Phn,@Email,@Username,@Password,@SecurityQuestion,@Hint)";
            cmd.CommandText = query1;
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today. You get this exception when the user you are using doesn't have the permissions to use the database. For testing it, you can login with the user using MS SQL Management Studio, and try to execute the query.
Check which groups the user is assigned to, make it a **db_owner** f.e., and check that it does not belong to **db_denydatareader** or **db_denydatawriter**